# Jupyterlab regular expression search

Tags: regex, jupyter-lab

When using search/replace tool in jupyterlab there is a message into the search bar saying "Use /re/ syntax for regexp search"

However I could not find an example on how exactly this syntax should be. I tried few options but none really worked.

Can anyone give me an example of how this syntax should be?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow.  Please read up on how to provide a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)  You may also benefit from [How to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [What is expected of SO users](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592/how-much-research-effort-is-expected-of-stack-overflow-users)

In this case, we need to see the "few options" that you tried

Answer (score 2):

In Jupiter lab 
you can use the shortcut <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>r</kbd> to replace a word.

Once you do that you will see a white space when you can type your sequence
if you want to use regexp you should write the sequence between slash.

For example, to replace line break by a comma you can type

```
/\n/
```

and you type Enter
you see another blank space where you can write:

Answer (score 1):

Apparently in order to search for a regular expression in jupyterlab one should enter the regex syntax between two slashes '/'.

For example to search for all sequences of the letter A one should enter in the search bar:
/A+/